# Running stored procedure from c# fails sometime but working when running from SQL editor

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which is taking more that 30 minutes to complete the task. When I am running that from SQL editor, it's working. But from website when I am calling it, getting stuck in middle and becomes never ending process. I tried to log any error but no error is there also.

Comment: Can you post what have you done?

Comment: Completely agree with @GrantWinney! Please add specifics to your question. Best regards,

Comment: If it takes 30 minutes to complete the query then most likely the problem you're having from the web site is that the query is timing out. The default timeout from a ADO.NET call is 30 *seconds*. At any rate, without seeing the C# code it's impossible to diagnose this problem, but I'd guess that you're catching a `SQLException` and then ignoring it. You can (a) change the `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` value to zero, which means no limit, or (b) catch and properly report the timeout, but you've still got a big problem: nobody wants to wait 30 minutes for a web page to respond.

Comment: I think you should have an exception, except when you have `try {} catch {}` over your code, So I suggest you to trace your code and found your exception.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of timeout.

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 30; // Increase value of 30 to get longer timeout.
```

I think you should also run execution plan on your queries in SP to see what does takes so long time. Does it takes equally long time to execute query from SQL as from code behind?